# Update the Nested Json with another Nested Json using Python

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

For example, I have one full set of nested JSON, I need to update this JSON with the latest values from another nested JSON.

Can anyone help me with this?

I want to implement this in Pyspark.

**Full Set Json look like this:**

```
{
    "email": "abctest@xxx.com", 
    "firstName": "name01", 
    "id": 6304,
    "surname": "Optional",
    "layer01": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key3": "value3", 
        "key4": "value4", 
        "layer02": {
            "key1": "value1", 
            "key2": "value2"
        }, 
        "layer03": [
            {
                "inner_key01": "inner value01"
            }, 
            {
                "inner_key02": "inner_value02"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "surname": "Required only$uid"
}
```

**LatestJson look like this:**

```
{
    "email": "test@xxx.com", 
    "firstName": "name01", 
    "surname": "Optional",
    "id": 6304,
    "layer01": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key3": "value3", 
        "key4": "value4", 
        "layer02": {
            "key1": "value1_changedData", 
            "key2": "value2"
        }, 
        "layer03": [
            {
                "inner_key01": "inner value01"
            }, 
            {
                "inner_key02": "inner_value02"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "surname": "Required only$uid"
}
```

In above for `id=6304` we have received updates for the `layer01.layer02.key1` and `emailaddress` fileds.

So I need to update these values to full JSON, Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Do you always want to get for each `id` the values from the latest JSON version regardless of null updates for example?

Comment: @blackbishop , ya based on id we need to update the json, Can help me with sample code in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the 2 JSON files into Spark data frames and do a `left_join` to get updates from the latest JSON data :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

full_json_df = spark.read.json(full_json_path, multiLine=True)
latest_json_df = spark.read.json(latest_json_path, multiLine=True)

updated_df = full_json_df.alias("full").join(
    latest_json_df.alias("latest"),
    F.col("full.id") == F.col("latest.id"),
    "left"
).select(
    F.col("full.id"),
    *[
        F.when(F.col("latest.id").isNotNull(), F.col(f"latest.{c}")).otherwise(F.col(f"full.{c}")).alias(c)
        for c in full_json_df.columns if c != 'id'
    ]
)

updated_df.show(truncate=False)

#+----+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
#|id  |email       |firstName|layer01                                                                                              |surname |
#+----+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
#|6304|test@xxx.com|name01   |[value1, value2, value3, value4, [value1_changedData, value2], [[inner value01,], [, inner_value02]]]|Optional|
#+----+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

**Update:**

If the schema changes between *full* and *latest* JSONs, you can load the 2 files into the same data frame (this way the schemas are being merged) and then deduplicate per `id`:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

merged_json_df = spark.read.json("/path/to/{full_json.json,latest_json.json}", multiLine=True)

# order priority: latest file then full
w = Window.partitionBy(F.col("id")).orderBy(F.when(F.input_file_name().like('%latest%'), 0).otherwise(1))

updated_df = merged_json_df.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(w))\
    .filter("rn = 1")\
    .drop("rn")

updated_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, One more issue I am facing here, in the latest Nested json I will not get the complete json, I will get only partial json, If you apply above code I am getting error like (org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve &#39;`latest.Document`&#39; given input columns:), Can you help me on this

Comment: I am geeting latest Json like this  {
    "email": "test@xxx.com", 
    "firstName": "name01", 
    "surname": "Optional",
    "id": 6304,
    "layer01": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": "value2", 
        "key3": "value3", 
        "key4": "value4", 
        "layer02": {
            "key1": "value1_changedData", 
            "key2": "value2"
        },}

Comment: If I am not getting some column in latest json, is there any possibility to pull that column from full json, By the above code full and latest have to be same no of columns(I mean same schema)

Comment: The above code is failing,  If the schema is miss match  But for me I will not getting same schema for the latest json, Can you please help me on this

Comment: @Pradeep Ok. Do you have any date in the data that identifies latest from full ? Or maybe using the file names ?

Comment: I will use based on file name

Comment: I am attaching my full json and latest Json file in below link for refrence, I need to update latest json data in full Json, Link is             https://github.com/namanipradeep/Nested-Json-Update

Comment: the above code is `not working as expected, the updated_df is having the latest_df data, I need the latest_df is update into fullset_df,  if possible can we connect for 5 mins(in any online tool) , Thank you in advance

Comment: I attached my lattest and full json in git hub, in latest json some of the blocks missing and some of the element values updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228101/discussion-between-blackbishop-and-pradeep).